# JavaScript current position dots (to show were you are)

Tags: javascript, titanium, carousel

Hello I´m having a bit of trouble to fix my carousel dots (the ones that show your current position, for example if you´re on image three then it could look like this: ●●◦●●●●●●●●).

p.s I´m not interested in a jQuery solution.

Today I´m doing this:

1. I have a variable that check the activePage (to mark out the white dot) and then I do a for loop to see where I shall put a white dot and where to put the other black dots, but this does not work. I´ll post my code below:

   // I will later assign this variable to a view that I have declared that will show the dots (I´m working on a Titanium project)
       var x = '';

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < mySlideViews.length; i++){
       if (activeSlideNbr == 0){
       // This is the first image and I want to set the first dot to a white dot
           x = '◦' + x;
       }
       // This is the last image and I want to set the last dot to a white dot
       else if (activeSlideNbr == mySlideViews.length -1){
           x ='◦' + x;
       }
       // if the active page is neither in the start or end
       else if (i == activeSlideNbr){
           x = '◦' + x; 
       }
       // to set out the black dots
       else{
           x =  x + '●';
       }   
   }
   ```

I would really appreciate some help, if you need more information please let me know.

Comment: What actually is the problem you are having with your code?

Comment: First get this view:
◦●●●●●●●●●●
And then the dots don´t move anymore for some reason (in the code above).

Comment: I see. Could this suggest that `activeSlideNbr` is always zero?

Comment: I have code that changes activeSlideNbr depending on slide and I have checked that variable and it´s correct.

Comment: have you checked the value of activeSlideNbr in the for loop above?

Comment: Yes and it follows the active style number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but I think this is what you are looking for:

```
var activeSlideNbr = 3;
var mySlideViews = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

var t = [];
while (t.length < mySlideViews.length) {
    t.push('●');
}
t[activeSlideNbr] = '◦';

console.log(t.join("")); //●●●◦●●●
```

There is no need for a loop to check where to put the white circle. You can just create an Array with all black circles and then put the white circle on the right index. To create a string from the array, you can use the `join` method.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8agW/)**